# What causes an object to be more reflective than refractive?

Tags: optics, photons, reflection, refraction

This is a question that a high school student asked me and I couldn't give him a satisfactory answer. He started by saying that

> An object appears red because the energy corresponding to a "red" (don't take it literally) photon isn't equal to that of the energy gap of the elctronic energy levels of the object.

> And now if I take the same object in complete dark and shine a red laser from above why don't I see a red beam coming out from the bottom surface the object ?

My first reponse was that 'since the object is opaque it reflects most of the red light falling on it' but he wasn't convinced and I think that he is basically trying to ask **what causes an object to be more reflective than refractive from the atomic point of view** .

Can someone help me with this ?

Comment: Does your object has a smooth surface?

Comment: @Pradyuman not necessarily. It maybe something likr an opaque object with glass like surface .

Comment: Are you sure that glass like opaque surface are not reflective?

Comment: @Pradyuman well they are reflective but the question that the boy asked was more about why reflective and not transparent?

Comment: The 2 quotes of the student seems related to transparency of some isolators to a range of frequencies, according to electronic band theory. But I think it is not the case for high school.